# I'm Converting HTML to Wordpress: Content on page non-cooporative

Tags: html, wordpress, css, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my first HTML to Wordpress conversion that I am doing for a bakery.  I've attempted to trouble shoot with the wordpress codex and forums with non-successful responses.

The following scenarios are for a full-width page.  I'm sure it's something simple (I could be wrong) but I'm not seeing it.

Scenario 1:  When I type the text alone, the alignment works just fine but, the return key between paragraphs will not separate the paragraphs like it should

Scenario 2:  The image alignment to the right moves only 1 sentence line next to the picture and the rest below it.

Scenario 3:  When inserting an image or a table, everything moves out of the designated container (div) and losing the style set to it.

http://www.treunorth.com/pennycakes/about/

Is there a line of code I need to add to the 'page-full.php' or adjust the css to make this work?

page-full.php:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page - Full Width */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Page Article -->

<div class="clear"></div> 

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<section id="story" class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div class="story-top grid_16"></div>

    <div class="story grid_16">
        <h1 class="meander"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p class="m500">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'pennycakes' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </p><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>
    <div class="story-bottom grid_16"></div>

</section>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<div class="clear"></div> 

<!-- //Page Article -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.container_16 .grid_16 {
    width: 972px;
    }

/*--------------------------------
 9) STORY
--------------------------------*/
#story { margin-top: 30px; }
.story-top { background: url('../css/images/bg-full-top.png') no-repeat center top; height: 30px; }
.story { background: url('../css/images/bg-full.png') repeat-y center top;}
.story h1 { font-size: 64px; color: #BF4A72; text-align: center; padding: 15px 0;}
.story p { font-size: 13px; color: #73656e; line-height: 19px; padding: 0 42px 0 42px; }
.story p.signature { background-position: 0 -949px; font-size: 26px; line-height: 51px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 42px; margin-top: 24px;}
.story-bottom { background: url('../css/images/bg-full-bottom.png') no-repeat center top; height: 31px;}
```

Comment: Since you are running 'section id="story"', possibly try running your css as: #story p #story h1 etc... You have the nifty Under Construction dealie going on in the site, so hard to see how it's rendering. Unless you have a plugin that stops it from doing it. WP will auto add <p> tags. Since it's your first run at it, might point out to check if you are editing in the WYSIWYG tab, or the HTML tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table has no width, neither has the cells in it. So styling it is not easy...

The paragraph tag has some styles also. Like a line height of 19px f.x and more.

Also most styles isn't inherited from the div to a table that is in it. You need to ad some styles to the table also.

Comment: so i will play with the paragraph styles some more, see if I can create that break

Comment: So I will play with the paragraph styles some more, see if I can create that break.  The problem is that I shouldn't have to add the <p> tag in the wordpress back-end for the content, I was trying to avoid that by adding

'<p class="m500">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</p>'

Is there a way I can have the '<p>' tags added automatically so I can keep this stupid simple for the business owner to edit?

Also, I added styles to the table but it still jumps out of the padding styles that I have set

'.story p { font-size: 13px; color: #73656e; line-height: 19px; padding: 0 42px 0 42px; }'

Answer (score 0):

You have missed few paragraph tags. Put these text in paragraph tag in about page

```
<p>I am a trained chef. I went to school at the California Culinary Academy in San Francisco. There I took courses in baking. Through my journey of gaining experience in the field I spent a year of that working in a bakery specializing in cake decorating. Post bakery my cake journey has gained me experience state side and 2 years in Finland baking cakes in restaurants and for family and friends.</p>
```

and

```
<p>I am a trained chef. I went to school at the California Culinary Academy in San Francisco. There I took courses in baking. Through my journey of gaining experience in the field I spent a year of that working in a bakery specializing in cake decorating. Post bakery my cake journey has gained me experience state side and 2 years in Finland baking cakes in restaurants and for family and friends.
</p>
```

Comment: The problem that I'm having is to have the `<p>` tags added automatically so the owner of the business can use this in a stupid simple manor.  The way I was trying to fix this was adding the p tags surrounding the wp-content in the code. `<p class="m500"><?php the_content(); ?></p>`